# How to set preferredRenderingAPI for ARSCNView in Xcode IB

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, arscnview

In my ARKit application ARSCNView is initialized and attached to ViewController internally based on storyboard file structure. So in function viewDidLoad I have already initialized view.
But the problem is it uses default rendering API metal. But I would like to change it to OpenGL ES2. In Apple documentation I read that preferredRenderingAPI can be somehow changed in IB inspector. But I don't understand how. There are no any examples of how to do this?
Or maybe I still change it from the code, even though the view is initialized from IB?

Answer (score 0):

Just open your Main.storyboard (or whatever you have) in Xcode and navigate to the node Scene View of type SCNView in there. The Attributes inspector should allow you to change the renderer (Rendering API).
I've just tested it but it looked like my project didn't work the same as with metal.